# how to import google calendar data into database (mysql or mongodb)?

Tags: javascript, mysql, mongodb, calendar, google-calendar-api

I have integrated google calendar into my website to create new event, update and delete events from website itself . All functionality is working fine .Now I want to capture all these data into my database . I want to store all google calendar data into my database i.e. mysql or mongodb . Is it possible to sync these google calendar with databases ? If possible please guide me ?
Thanks !!

Comment: are you using calendar api? or caldev? provide a minimal example of what you have tried .

Comment: yes I am using calendar api

Comment: @AviSangray I have implemented the webapp like event management . I am able to implement CRUD functionality from my app into google calendar. But now I want to store all these event data into my database . So I am searching for that . But I didn't getting any reference for that .

Comment: just setup all existing data in mongo and keep it in sync using calendar api webhook. you would need to create another table to keep latest nextSyncToken from response which has to be called in request to get events endpoint to get only updates from last sync. deleted events are not returned make sure you enable them in request.

Comment: for event management you might need to do some extra work for recurring events. mongodb not gonna fit if you want to also create events from your app. as you would need some mysql extension to easily parse recurring events schedules

Comment: @AviSangray  If you have any reference doc or videos link please share it so I can get more idea about it . And thank you so much for kind help .

Comment: i'll give an answer with code by few hours for webhooks and data update to sql